# Most elegant way to position label under checkbox in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, checkbox, positioning

I want to have my bootstrap checkbox labels UNDER their checkboxes, looking like this:

[image: bootstrap checkbox labels UNDER their checkboxes]

My current code is this:

```
<div class="well container-fluid text-center">
    <img src="dummy.png" class="img-circle img-responsive" />
    </br>
    <lable for="check">Lable</lable>
    </br> 
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
</div>
```

...but this doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: In your picture, the checkbox is under the label. What you are asking for and the picture show are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't vouch for this being the most elegant or proper solution, but it is much better than using line breaks in your code. Check out the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/j9ZkOT7Chd)

```
<div class="container">
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="row">
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

Simply place your checkbox, then put the label in a new row.

Comment: @user3351652 don't forget to click the checkmark next to the answer if this helped you. Also, look into http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for more formatting help.